# Not able to Reindex Indexes when install magento by downloading code from magento connect

Tags: magento2, reindex

I have installed magento 2 by downloading code from magento connect. I have not used composer for it.

Now, I am not able to reindex indexes from CLI.

Please let me know how to reindex indexes in magento 2.

Comment: which error showing on run command.

Comment: Could not open input file: binmagento

Comment: Write your command which you run.

Comment: I have gone to the root directory of my magento instance in CLI and the run the following command:

php bin\magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I have made a mistake, now its worked for me. The command should be: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reindex in magento 2, go to the CLI and then the root folder of your magento installation and run the below command :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: I have tried this, but this is not working for me. Please let me know if there is any other way to reindex.

Comment: Thankyou. I have compared your command and mine. Then I found the change in my command and yours. It works for me.

Comment: accept and upvote if it helped

Comment: I have done that